# remove class from an element if any of the give classes match using javascript

Tags: javascript

i have a simple javascript function which removes a class from an element. The script i am using is

```
function removeclass(elementId, elementClass) {
    document.getElementById(elementId).className = document.getElementById(elementId).className.replace( ' '+elementClass , '' );
}
```

The html code i am using is

```
<div id="mine" class="hide show success fail">Class will be removed from here</div>
<button onclick="removeclass('mine', 'fail show success')" type="button">Remove Class</button>
```

now i want when click on Remove Class button it should replace the passed classes one by one if they exist in the div. How can i do that ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to split `elementClass` into an array so you can remove each one. Also, this is easier to do using the `classList` property than `className`.

```
function removeclass(elementId, elementClass) {
    var classes = elementClass.split(' ');
    var classList = document.getElementById(elementId).classList;
    classList.remove.apply(classList, classes);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"not-so-much-good" solution.

```js
  function removeClass(eId, klassName) {
    var el = document.getElementById(eId);
    klassName.split(" ").forEach(function(e){
      el.classList.remove(e);
    });
  }
```

```html
<div id="mine" class="hide show success">Class will be removed from here</div>
<button onclick="removeClass('mine', 'success show fail show')" type="button">Remove Class</button>
```